# Determining DST or CST timezone from UTC timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have UTC timeZone Date which I want to convert CST or DST based on whether DST is applied in the same city or not.

Since my browser is not based on same city so local time is no use of it.
example: my user is based on India but they will see data for NewYork Date also

I have a server based on NewYork so using SSR I can get date of the server but its always showing in CST how I can change the date into DST?

Comment: have you tried looking into any libraries such as moment js?

Comment: Cant use moment and another library since it will increase bundle size. That's like a last option

Comment: I mean if you are doing your conversions via node on the server side bundle size shouldn't matter too much

Comment: not sure moment works on SSR .  never tried can you suggest

Comment: SSR means server side rendered, and you have node.js as a tag, I just assumed you were using node.js to server up your app?

Comment: yes sorry for my ignorence . yes i can use moment using node but problem is its extra library for just one small function wanted to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

try this code. it might help you.

```
  let d = new Date()
  let utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
  let today = new Date(utc - (3600000 * 6))  // 6 is for cst timezone. we can change this to get other timezome . this is offset 

  let dd = today.getDate()
  let mm = today.getMonth()+1
  let yy = today.getFullYear()
  let hh = today.getHours()
  let i  = today.getMinutes()
  let sec = today.getSeconds()

  hh = hh.toString().length<2?("0"+hh):hh
  mm = mm.toString().length<2?("0"+mm):mm
  i = i.toString().length<2?"0"+i:i
  sec = sec.toString().length<2?"0"+sec:sec

  let timestamp = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yy+' '+hh+':'+i+':'+sec
  console.log('timestamp ',timestamp)
```

Comment: the problem is I am not aware that it's CST or DST timezone.  since these timezone changes based on city .

Comment: ok based on city you can change the offset. in this case offset is  6 at line number 3. so you need to change it based on city just like if we change country time should show different.

Comment: Problem is offset of city . let say that city is plano in US which have two timezone CST and DST how will you determine from date that this is timeZoneoff set now for this date

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to convert a UTC date to a specific timezone. This will honour the local DST rules and is native JavaScript code (no libraries required!)

So, if we have a list of UTC dates, we can convert to a specific timezone. I've created a list of UTC dates and timezones and formatted the dates for that timezone and date.

You can select a different display locale of course, for example if you have Indian clients you could use "en-in" or whichever you decide is the best display locale.

You should be able to do any timezone conversion either on the server side or (preferably) on the client side. If you send all dates to the client in UTC format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ) you can convert to the client timezone in the client code.

```js
const displayLocale = "en-us"; // Set this to en-gb, en-in etc..
const uctDateList = [ new Date("2019-06-01T12:00:00Z"), new Date("2019-12-01T12:00:00Z")];
const timeZoneList = ['America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'Asia/Kolkata'];


uctDateList.forEach(utcDate => {
    console.log("\nServer Time: ", utcDate.toISOString());
  timeZoneList.forEach(timeZone => {
    console.log(`Time in timezone (${timeZone}):`, utcDate.toLocaleString(displayLocale, { timeZone }));
  })
});
```